# Python smtplib Accept Calendar Event

Tags: python

When Clicking accept in the email, and viewing it in the calendar it still says "has not accepted invite".  Im not quite sure why the response to accept the email is not being updated in the calendar. Please help thanks!  I am using outlook as the email service.  Thanks again for the help much appreciated

```
#imports

import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formatdate
from email import encoders
import os,datetime
COMMASPACE = ', '

CRLF = "\r\n"

#Account that creats the Meeting
login = "admin@gmail.com"
password = "Password"
attendees = ["admin@gmail.com", "user1@gmail.com", "user2@gmail.com"]
organizer = "ORGANIZER;CN=Test:mailto:admin"+CRLF+"@gmail.com"
fro = "nickname <admin@gmail.com>"

ddtstart = datetime.datetime.now()
dtoff = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
dur = datetime.timedelta(hours = 1)
ddtstart = ddtstart +dtoff
dtend = ddtstart + dur
dtstamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
dtstart = ddtstart.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
dtend = dtend.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")

description = "DESCRIPTION: test invitation from pyICSParser"+CRLF
attendee = ""
for att in attendees:
    attendee += "ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-    PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE"+CRLF+" ;CN="+att+";X-NUM-GUESTS=0:"+CRLF+" mailto:"+att+CRLF
ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR"+CRLF+"PRODID:pyICSParser"+CRLF+"VERSION:2.0"+CRLF+"CALSCALE:GREGORIAN"+CRLF
ical+="METHOD:REQUEST"+CRLF+"BEGIN:VEVENT"+CRLF+"DTSTART:"+dtstart+CRLF+"DTEND:"+dtend+CRLF+"DTSTAMP:"+dtstamp+CRLF+organizer+CRLF
ical+= "UID:FIXMEUID"+dtstamp+CRLF
ical+= attendee+"CREATED:"+dtstamp+CRLF+description+"LAST-MODIFIED:"+dtstamp+CRLF+"LOCATION:"+CRLF+"SEQUENCE:0"+CRLF+"STATUS:CONFIRMED"+CRLF
ical+= "SUMMARY:test "+ddtstart.strftime("%Y%m%d @ %H:%M")+CRLF+"TRANSP:OPAQUE"+CRLF+"END:VEVENT"+CRLF+"END:VCALENDAR"+CRLF

eml_body = "Event on Calendar test"
eml_body_bin = "This is the email body in binary - two steps"
msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msg['Reply-To']="admin@gmail.com"
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
msg['Subject'] = "Testing Event"+dtstart
msg['From'] = fro
msg['To'] = ",".join(attendees)

part_email = MIMEText(eml_body,"html")
part_cal = MIMEText(ical,'calendar;method=REQUEST')

msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg.attach(msgAlternative)

ical_atch = MIMEBase('application/ics',' ;name="%s"'%("invite.ics"))
ical_atch.set_payload(ical)
encoders.encode_base64(ical_atch)
ical_atch.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"'%("invite.ics"))

eml_atch = MIMEText('', 'plain')
encoders.encode_base64(eml_atch)
eml_atch.add_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', "")

msgAlternative.attach(part_email)
msgAlternative.attach(part_cal)

mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.outlook.com', 587)
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.login(login, password)
mailServer.sendmail(fro, attendees, msg.as_string())
mailServer.close()

print("Email Sent")
```